# OnClick open URL (Json, ListView) Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-listview

hello i have a list of item (listview) in json here's the code:

```
listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });
```

And this is the Json file:

```
"title": "Dawn of the Planet of the Apes",
    "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg",
    "rating": 8.3,
    "releaseYear": 2014,
    "genre": ["Action", "Drama", "Sci-Fi"]
},
{
    "title": "District 9",
    "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2.jpg",
    "rating": 8,
    "releaseYear": 2009,
    "genre": ["Action", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller"]
},
{
    "title": "Transformers: Age of Extinction",
    "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/3.jpg",
    "rating": 6.3,
    "releaseYear": 2014,
    "genre": ["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi"]
},
{
    "title": "X-Men: Days of Future Past",
    "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/4.jpg",
    "rating": 8.4,
    "releaseYear": 2014,
    "genre": ["Action", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller"]
},
```

I want to put a Link in every item of the json, something like "url": "http://google.com" and that the app open the link (Action_VIEW). Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Please Look into:

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                           movie.setUrlLink("http://google.com");

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        }
```

And for Action View: Put these Code in the Click Listner:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(movie.getUrlLink())));
```

Note: I think You know about the how to get the data from bean.

Comment: hello can i contact you? What's your mail?